# find service account on remote hosts

Tags: powershell

Could you please advise how to find all servers where a specific service account is being used to start Windows services?

I am trying this in PowerShell with these code:

```
Clear-Host
$address = Get-Content '.\asg connections.csv'
$serviceName = "startname='NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService'"
gwmi Win32_Service -Filter $serviceName -Computer $address
```

Above piece of code works for "localhost", but gives below error for the remote hosts:

```
gwmi : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 
(E_ACCESSDENIED))
At F:\Temp\powershell\play.ps1:30 char:1
+ gwmi win32_service -filter $serviceName -computer $address
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The user account you're running the script with has no rights to logon (network logon) on the target system. Do you use your script in a domain or a workgroup environment?

Comment: have you tried with and enterprise admin ? He/She should be able to do that.

Comment: @TobyU Thanks for the note, I am using script in a domain, it is AD privileged account, which has admin rights on these remote machines.

Comment: @RanadipDutta thanks for note. I think enterprise admin is overkill, because I am using AD account, which has admin rights on those remote hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use PowerShell remoting you implicitly trying to use the credentials your current Windows session is logged into your machine with on the target machines.

It looks like you do not have any rights with your current set of credentials on those machines.

Are the target machines joined into the same domain as your current user credentials?
If you have a set of working credentials you can log onto those machines with, you can add it in your command with:

```
Clear-Host
#Promts you for the username and password you wish to save to a credential object
$Cred = Get-Credential
$address = Get-Content '.\asg connections.csv'
$serviceName = "startname='NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService'"
gwmi Win32_Service -Filter $serviceName -Computer $address -Credential $Cred
```

If the script needs to run automated there are a few different ways to save credential passwords either into an encrypted textfile that can only be decrypted by the user account that encrypted it, or using the build in Windows Credential Vault.

Comment: thank you for this good answer. I am using script in a domain, it is AD privileged account, which has admin rights on these remote machines. I am running my script while logged in under this AD account. I have used Get-Credential and with my credentials for this AD account result is still the same as without Get-Credential.

Comment: This answer is no where related to the OPs question. Its the issue with the privilege and not with how he wants to store the password.